# Software to review all svn commits

Tags: subversion

I need some software which allows me to read all svn commits as unified diffs. And when I say read, I really just need the ability to read the unified diff for each svn commit, and then mark the commit as read and accepted.

So the perfect software, would simply show a list of svn commits I have not read yet, and for each commit show a unified diff and a button saying "Read done (Show next commit)".

I don't need the ability to write comments, or reject anything. I just need something which 
helps me read all svn commits.

Extra bonus points if it is integrated into Eclipse, but not a requirement as long as it work On Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [specto](http://specto.sourceforge.net/) or [SVN::Notify](http://search.cpan.org/~dwheeler/SVN-Notify-2.67/lib/SVN/Notify.pm) or [Subversion Repository Monitor](https://ghost.tweakblogs.net/blog/3073/subversion-repository-monitor.html)

If you are OK with [Wine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)) (run windows applications on Linux) then these are really handy tools:

1. [TortoiseSVN Project Monitor](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-projectmonitor-maindialog.html#tsvn-projectmonitor-maindialog-buttons).
2. [CommitMonitor](https://tools.stefankueng.com/CommitMonitor.html).

All these tools have the ability to do what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you know if CommitMonitor supports the "svn+ssh" protocol? Or does it only work with http(s):// ?